# prevent website files from being downloaded from direct URL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a site in Wordpress that has a PDF link for download that is currently on a  password protected page. I am wondering how I can prevent that PDF from being downloaded if someone happens to get the direct file path url for that PDF. Is there maybe a plugin that would help? The site is on AWS so I can't change the .htaccess file as I've seen most people suggest.

Comment: If it truly is password protected, getting the full URL would make little difference. They would need the password too. Care to clarify?

Comment: Its password protected in that you can't get to the page that the link is on without being logged in. So the file itself is not password protected, but the page it is on is. I just edited my question as I see how I made that confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach with AWS is to host your files on S3 and use S3 PreSigned URLs with an expiration.

From your protected by password pages, generated presigned urls in place of the regular download link. Then protect your S3 bucket by making it NOT public. The presigned url will be required to download the file.

A Google search will turn up lots of examples with source code on how to do this. Very easy to do.

[Creating a presigned request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html)

Comment: It's important to mention that presigned URLs also have a timeout so even if someone does get a hold of an old URL, it won't work.